# Bootstrap 3 modal-backdrop not graying out

Tags: css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

My modal window appears transparent and the background is not grayed out over the page.  The HTML format looks correct compared with other examples.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zc5e7x1w/)

```
<p>
Some back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuff
Some back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuff
Some back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuff
Some back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuff
Some back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuff
Some back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuffSome back ground stuff
</p>

<div class="modal-backdrop">
  <div class="modal show" id="myModal" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">          
          <h4 class="modal-title">My Modal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>My Modal Body</p>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  background-color: gray !important;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing a width/height declaration.

The following seems to be doing the trick:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.8);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/t5u31L20/1/)